# How can I see all ingoing requests?

Tags: networking

So I want to write a program that let's 2 computers in different networks across the internet communicate. Code is not the problem, it is receiving the messages. I fear the firewall will do its job and stop my messages, but is there a program that I can use to see all incoming requests with content? Maybe before and after firewall?

Comment: You can use packet sniffers like Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Applications which provide this kind of functionality are called packet sniffers. However, it highly depends on your firewall implementation on how to do this exactly.

Comment: I'll just turn it off. What's the worst that could happen. Or is there an easy and safe port to use for this